# Resizing a fluid width section in IE

Tags: html, css

My site is fluid width, but one section doesn't resize correctly - where the right-hand image is at the end of the header. Here's the CSS:

```
#middle-top {
height:68px;
float:left;
width:81%;
border-left:1px solid #Fafafa;
}
```

I've used media screen style sheets, but it still doesn't work properly across all browsers - i.e. in IE.

If anyone could perhaps have a look and reduce the window size with any suggestions it'd be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `img` tags. give the same images as background images to `div#middle-top` and position it to right.

Something like this:

```
 background-image:  Image url1 , Image url2; /* does not support IE7 and IE8 */
 background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
 background-position: right;
```

Update:

**Or else**

Give right side images in percentages, something like :

```
img#heart { width: 20%; }
```